# Finding Statically Allocated Data Blocks in a Static Library

Tags: c, linux, memory, assembly

I've got a small static library (`.a`).  In the static library is a pointer that points to a large, statically allocated, 1D array.

When I link my code to this library, the pointer's address is hardcoded in various locations, easily found through the disassembly.  The issue is, I'd like my code to be able to have access to this array (the library is faulting, and I want to know why).

Naturally, it would be trivial to get that pointer by disassembling, hardcoding that address into my code, and then recompiling.  That wouldn't be a problem except the library can be configured in different ways with other modules, and the array's pointer changes depending on what modules are linked in.

What are my options for getting that pointer?  Because the starting state of the array is predictable, I could walk through memory, catching segfaults with a signal handler, until I found something that looks reasonable.  Is there a better way?

Comment: If it is your library, can't you just change the interface to expose it?

Comment: Nope; it's not my library.  It's just broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your library is a `.a` archive, I'll assume you are on some kind of UNIX.

The global array should have a symbolic name associated with it. Your job would be easier or harder depending on what kind of symbol describes it.

If there is a *global* symbol describing this array, then you can just reference it directly, e.g.

```
extern char some_array[];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) printf("%2d: 0x%2x\n", i, some_array[i]);
```

If the symbol is local, then you can first globalize it with `objcopy --globalize-symbol=some_array`, then proceed as above.

So how can you determine what is the symbol describing that array? Run `objdump -dr foo.o`, where `foo.o` contains instructions which you know reference that array. The relocation that will appear next to the referring instruction will tell you the name.

Finally, run `nm foo.o | grep some_array`. If you see `00000XX D some_array`, you are done -- the array is globally visible (same for `B`). If you see `000XX d some_array`, you need to globalize it first (likewise for `b`).

Update:

> The -dr to objectdump didn't work

Right, because the symbol turned out to be local, the relocation probably referred to `.bss + 0xNNN`.

> `00000000006b5ec0 b grid`
>   `00000000006c8620 b grid`
>   `00000000006da4a0 b grid`
>   `00000000006ec320 b grid`
>   `00000000006fe1a0 b grid`

You must have run `nm` on the final linked executable, not on individual `foo.o` objects inside your archive. There are five *separate* static arrays called `grid` in your binary, only the first one is the one you apparently care about.

> declaring "extern int grid[];" and using it gives an undefined reference

That's expected for local symbols: the code in the library was something like:

```
// foo.c
static char grid[1000];
```

and you can't reference this `grid` from outside `foo.o` without globalizing the symbol first.

> I'm not allowed to run a changed binary of the library on our server for security reasons

I hope you understand that that argument is *total BS*: if you can link your own code into that binary, then you can do *anything* on the server (subject to user-id restrictions); you are already trusted. Modifying third-party library should be the *least* worry of the server's admin if he doesn't trust you.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Yes, Ubuntu 10.04.  The -dr to objectdump didn't work, but I did find the array using nm.  The relevant output was something like: "00000000006b5ec0 b grid\n00000000006c8620 b grid\n00000000006da4a0 b grid\n00000000006ec320 b grid\n00000000006fe1a0 b grid".

Comment: The address 0x6b5ec0 is the same address referenced in the assembly (though I wonder why the multiple lines of output?).  Unfortunately, declaring "extern int grid[];" and using it gives an undefined reference, so I suspect it was declared static global.  I'm not allowed to run a changed binary of the library on our server for security reasons, so unfortunately I can't just globalize it, even for a test.

Comment: The multiple lines of output smell of a programming error. This is probably a `static` variable in the original code and is actually instantiated in three different compilation units. So there is not one array but three of them and the malfunctioning that you observe could just be for that reason.

Comment: @JensGustedt I don't agree with your comment *at all*. What's wrong with declaring 5 separate instances of static array, that all happen to be named `grid`, but have no relationship with each other?

Comment: @EmployedRussian, nothing wrong per se, it just would be the first thing I'd look at :)

Comment: @EmployedRussian: I completely agree with the "security reasons" being BS.  It's not my policy.  And it's pretty clear that the operation I'm trying to do is an example of a potential security hole.